# F# Match with discriminated unions

Tags: .net, types, f#

I define 2 discriminated unions: "Direction" and "TurnCommand":

```
type Direction = 
| South of string
| East of string
| North of string
| West of string

type TurnCommand = 
| Left of string
| Right of string
```

Then I define function to have new Direction after making TurnCommand:

```
type Turn = Direction -> TurnCommand -> Direction
```

Here is not working implementation of this function:

```
let Do:Turn = fun(startDirection) (turn) -> 
    match startDirection, turn with
    | South, Left  -> East 
    | East,  Left  -> North
    | North, Left  -> West
    | West,  Left  -> South
    | South, Right -> West 
    | East,  Right -> South
    | North, Right -> East
    | West,  Right -> North
```

There is error: "*The constructor applied to 0 arguments but expects 1*". 
I understand that it expects string value but I need to match types here. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you defined your constructors (e.g. `South of string`), you said that they required a `string` argument. When pattern matching on those constructors, you have to use a variable pattern to store the value given to the constructor (or `_` to ignore it) and when constructing a value you have to provide a string too: `South s1, Left _  -> East "a string"`. If you don't need any kind of value associated with your constructors just drop the `of string` part from their definition.